# How to configure Linux to authenticate users based on Keycloak user database?

Tags: login, authentication, ldap

I have an existing user database in Keycloak.

I want to build a Linux machine which logs in users according to the user database in Keycloak (username, password).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to implement the following:

1. add NSS passwd map data to Keycloak user accounts (POSIX-UID, primary POSIX-GID, etc.)
2. implement a service pulling NSS data from Keycloak and make it locally available on Linux system
3. implement a PAM module sending password authentication requests to Keycloak

While it's not impossible it would be quite some development work.

The usual way of having centralized user management for Unix/Linux is to set up a LDAP server storing the relevant data. And then configure Keycloak to use this LDAP server for retrieving user data and check passwords.

There are ready-to-use solutions available like [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org) or my own [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com).

Comment: Hi, I would like to know more on this answer. How to implement all the above 3 steps. is there any step by step link available ?